# React on Application Event within Component Sub Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

i am facing a challenge in a Lightning Component which i suspect to be a timing or parallelism issue, but cannot get my head arround unfortunately.
Maybe this is something obvious somebody of you experienced before and can point me in some directions for further investigation?

As presented in the screenshots below i am trying to react to a button click within a component via an Application Event in a second component. Those two components are nested on the same level within one grouping component.

This second component itself is composed of some markup (for now only a label) and another subcomponent (this one holds some more markup, js logic and also an Backend Apex Controller to fetch some data).
While i am able to react on the first button click, meaning to the Application Event dispatched, in the Label (changing its content), the subcomponent doInit only reacts to the Application Event on a subsequent button click.

The subcomponent Application Event handler calls the doInit which works fine if i embed this subcomponent in a standalone app.

I hope this explanation is sufficient to understand the issue.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Clemens

[image: Component Structure]

[image: Screenshot Accordion CMP is populated]

[image: Screenshot Accordion Section Button Clicked x 1]

[image: Screenshot Accordion Section Button Clicked x 2]

Comment: `doInit` only runs when the component is initiated, and shouldn't be used to "detect" when an application event is fired.  Try using an `aura:handler` to capture the app events

Comment: i am actually using an aura:handler to register to the Application Event and point it to the doInit function:

 <aura:handler event="c:accordionsectionclicked" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>

Comment: Try refactoring it so it doesn't share the `doInit` method.  I would have a helper method that you can call within `doInit` as well as the new `handleAppEvent` controller method that actually performs the logic you're looking for

Comment: Hi @BrianMiller, thanks for the idea.
After decoupling the code and first thinking it didn´t help i actually found another flaw in my flow.
This actually seems to work, thanks.